# Why has this type of research fallen out of grace?

Tags: reference-request, history-economic-thought

I am reading *Dasgupta's* Very Short Introduction to Economics. He talks about culture. Specifically the work of Max Weber trying to explain the influence of protestant ethic on the rise of capitalism. After that he says:

> Using culture to explain economic performance hasn't been popular among social scientists in recent decades; but there has been a revival.

Why has there been a decline of interest on this type of research? What kind of research replaced it? And finally, what modern work follows Weber's line of research?